# StreamWriter cannot write into a file although it is closed

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I have the following problem:

I use this code to open a file and write to it:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(saveDir + @"\" +   saveFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    streamWriter.Write("Test");
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

but in the "using" line it tells me that it can not open the file because it is used by another process but the file is not open and isn't used. What's wrong?
I searched around this forum and the internet but I can't find a solution.

Comment: `but the file is not open and isn't used` - are you sure? Such messages are very rarely lying...

Comment: Clearly Windows thinks the file is in use.

Comment: no it's not used at all. How to solve that?

Comment: How have you checked, that its not in use?

Comment: You can solve using Handle which displays information about open handles for any process in the system. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx or the GUI-based ProcessExplorer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: How to check that? I created it via the File.Create Command. It's an empty file. I even closed VisualStudio and reopened it. The file is closed and I don't know what process should use the file.

Comment: Are you creating the file in the same code as when you are trying to open it? If so, post all the relevant code

Comment: i know this. you think it isn't used but windows thinks so... sometimes a reboot is helpful. Check also (maybe more interesting with StreamWriter) that the file isn't readonly.

Comment: modify the filename and try again...

Comment: Ok thanks! I deleted a if command where he checks if the file exists and creates it otherwise. I used the OpenOrCreate Command. Now it works fine!

Comment: This might be hold by w3p process or asp.net local webserver if you are using asp.net application. Explorer can also hold if you are checking if file has been created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` instead of creating the file "manually":

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(saveDir + @"\" + saveFile, 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    streamWriter.Write("Test");
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```